# Android Release Build

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I was facing a problem earlier this week.  When I tried to do the Android release build it seemed to show the following error --

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzjm.class

I was wondering how I got this error and how to fix it.  It seems as if the problem was inside the build.gradle files. Here they are --

App Level -

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.unknown.app"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 20
        versionName "2.34"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads'
}

    compile project(path: ':BaseGameUtils')
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is the top level  --

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Thanks for all help. I have been having this issue for a little while. I could not find the answer in any other stack overflow questions. Thanks Again.

Comment: Try to clean the project as well, or delete the build and bin folders from your project

Comment: Ok. I will see. Thanks.

Comment: Did not work though thanks for the help.

Comment: Just throwing out an idea, even though I can't find anything, could it be because you compile the project BaseGameUtils twice? If not, try removing firebase and play-services temporarily to see what is the cause, add just one at a time.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if the BaseGameUtils module was causing the problem. I am not sure why but reomving it, and replacing the BaseGameUtils for some reason did the trick, and the error did not show anymore. Thanks for all the help along the way of figuring out the issue.

Comment: Glad you found it. Are you sure it is the BaseGameUtils as a whole? Was there any line like `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'` and `compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2')` inside BaseGameUtils build module? Did you remove both `compile project(':BaseGameUtils')` and `compile project(**path:** ':BaseGameUtils')` or only one of the two?

Comment: I removed both, though I guess I could have excluded a few libraries from that module, though it worked  at least. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

the error explains itself, it means that it found two libraries which are the same

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
```

by including `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2` you are actually including all the play-service libraries, please remove it and you should be fine or remove the others "below it".

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will check.

Comment: That helped, though did not fix the error. Thanks again for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

you are including the 
'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'
 and
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
but firebase already includes the second library so you don't have to include this one just use the ads library from firebase

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will check.

Comment: I edited the code with the changes though it still gave the same error. Thanks again for your help though.

Comment: I am editing the code to show how it looks like after the changes.

Comment: actually firebase is already using these libraries so may be there are some other duplications also try removing last three libraries, it worked fine with my project

Comment: Ok. I will see. Thanks.

Comment: I will edit the code with a few changes, though it still does not work.

Comment: Just edited. I excluded a library of ads from the play services, though the same error is still showing.